# Arrayformula addition of two cells

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I have a simple formula that calculates the time based on the cell above it and a cell in another column.

How do I translate this to an array formula?

(in cell L2)

```
=arrayformula(L1:L18+E2:E19)
```

this is my intuition but it results in a `#ref`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that range of where array formula to be rolled out is empty

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(L1:L18+E2:E19)
```

[image: 0]

---

if this is in **L2** eg. running total then:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="", ,SUMIF(ROW(E2:E), "<="&ROW(E2:E), E2:E)+L1))
```

[image: 0]